# unexpected behaviour of mozilla firefox

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a web-server which serves static pages only.
Here is the code of my ultra mini web server.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class MyWebServer{

    static ServerSocket serSocket = null ;

    static{
        try {
            serSocket = new ServerSocket(80) ;
            System.out.println("Server started successfully....\n\n") ;
        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println( io.getMessage() );
            System.exit(1) ;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args){

        while(true){
            try {
                new Thread( new ServingThread( serSocket.accept() ) ).start() ;
            } catch (IOException io) {
                System.out.println(io.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

class ServingThread implements Runnable{
    private Socket socket ;

    public ServingThread(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket ;
        System.out.println("Receives a new browser request from " + socket);
    }

    public void run() {
        BufferedReader in = null ;
        PrintWriter out = null ;

        try {

            //reading request headers from browser starts here
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String str = ".";
            while (!str.equals("")){
                str = in.readLine();
                //System.out.println(str);
            }
            System.out.println("\n\n");
            //reading request headers from browser ends here


            //writing output on outputstream starts here
            out = new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream(), true ) ;

            int i = (int) ( Math.random() * 10) ;
            out.println(i) ;
            System.out.println(i) ;
            //writing output on outputstream ends here

            socket.close() ;
            System.out.println("Request successfully fulfilled.\n") ;
        }
        catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println(io.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, but **some times (not always)**

- my mozilla firefox client
  automatically sends a request, when i
  add a new tab (Ctrl + T) or closes an
  existing tab.
- When i request for
  **http://localhost/** , single digit gets displayed on my browser. But the
  server's console shows that it get 2
  or 3 requests, so, it shows 2 or 3 numbers
  accordingly.

I googled a lot but don't get an satisfactory answer for this.

Any thoughts/explanations are highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Does it have to be Java? Here's an ultra mini web server in Ruby that runs from a USB drive on Mac, Windows, and Linux. Pinky: http://yellosoft.us/index.php?id=86

Comment: yes, i am using java. any java link :-).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm assuming you're doing this as an exercise to learn about sockets / http / etc... Because if you're *really* trying to implement a web server, you should seriously consider using an existing one or at least looking at its source - there's a LOT of stuff involved in even the most simplistic HTTP server implementation.

That said, your "server" :-) doesn't implement [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) properly (doesn't return status code, for one) so browser's behavior is really undetermined here - it may attempt to retry the same request multiple times or it may not. Caching issue may be at play here too - once you do implement HTTP, you'll need to send appropriate caching headers if you don't want "new tab" to repeat request.

Comment: any online reference for simplistic java implemented web-servers with source code. :-) .

Comment: Here's a list of OS java web servers: http://java-source.net/open-source/web-servers. And here's a (quite outdated, but still useful) tutorial on writing one: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Networking/Webserver/

Google comes up with quite a few links as well: http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=simple+java+web+server

Comment: thnx ChssPly. I am already done with the second link. It also don't implement HTTP properly.

Comment: It does, actually. A very limited subset of HTTP protocol, of course, but it handles GET / HEAD methods and returns status codes properly.